# Navigating around website adds a [object object] to URL after clicking around anchors

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

Thanks for reading. I just wanted to know why i get a "/index.html#[object Object]" at the end of URL when clicking around anchors on a single page website.

I would also like to know if i can remove it if it isn't too game changing with htaccess or resolve the issue that is occuring?

If you require more information that isn't in this help request feel free to ask :) !

The website [the-md.studio](https://the-md.studio)

Comment: Looks like your javascript are adding some object to the url or links, do you have it online to check?

Comment: Firstly, you need to understand what is that `#` for. You can check this document https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/190941?hl=en#:~:text=In%20a%20URL%2C%20a%20hash,of%20the%20page%20or%20website. `[object Object]` can be coming from your object data, it should be a string to display properly

Comment: @LinkStrifer Yes I do! https://the-md.studio/

Comment: @NickVu Ok ill try and read that document. Thank you!

Comment: @LinkStrifer Hey sorry to tag you again in this post. but im having issues with smooth scrolling on the webapp. Should I make a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your [custom.js](https://the-md.studio/assets/js/custom.js) file, this line (~147):

[image]

```js
window.location.hash = target;
```

target is not the selector, is a jquery element, so it's an object.

Change it for this one:

```js
window.location.hash = target.selector;
```

I think that's what you want

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much! Its not showing up anymore. Such a silly mistake >_<

Just gotta stop the ID Tag from appearing now :D

Solved.

Comment: Hey Link, Sorry to bother you again. But after the changes you recommended, the transition between each  nav anchor has become a tad choppy. Any ideas?

Comment: I can’t replicate your issue, here is running fine, on Edge for iOS, which browser are you using?

Comment: All good man. I just changed the value of scrollTop to something else. I will live with the hard scrolling.